# How do i compare and get expected result excel sheets in java?

Tags: java, xlsx

I have been given a problem where i have to compare excel sheets by using java. I have searched online and found a code. Even though it does not match my requirement fully i thought of modifying the code once it runs. but when i run it initially it said there were no POI libraries and threw some errors after downloading the required libraries from the web the code was error free but i am not knowing where should i give the path of my excel sheets to get compared. Since there are no sheets to compare i am getting the default result as output. Can anyone out here please help me on how and where to put the link of my excel documents in the code? TIA.

been trying only in eclipse as i dont have admin access to add external library files to tryin cmd.

```java
package org.apache.poi.ss.examples;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BorderStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Color;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DateUtil;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.FillPatternType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.HorizontalAlignment;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFColor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;


public class ExcelComparator {

    private static final String CELL_DATA_DOES_NOT_MATCH = "Cell Data does not Match ::";
    private static final String CELL_FONT_ATTRIBUTES_DOES_NOT_MATCH = "Cell Font Attributes does not Match ::";

    private static class Locator {
        Workbook workbook;
        Sheet sheet;
        Row row;
        Cell cell;
    }

    List<String> listOfDifferences = new ArrayList();

    public static void main(String[] args)throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 2 || !(new File(args[0]).exists()) || !(new File(args[1]).exists())) {
            System.err.println("java -cp <classpath> " + ExcelComparator.class.getCanonicalName() + " <workbook1.xls/x> <workbook2.xls/x");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        try(Workbook wb1 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(args[0]), null, true)) {
            try(Workbook wb2 = WorkbookFactory.create(new File(args[1]), null, true)) {
                for (String d : ExcelComparator.compare(wb1, wb2)) {
                    System.out.println(d);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public static List<String> compare(Workbook wb1, Workbook wb2) {
        Locator loc1 = new Locator();
        Locator loc2 = new Locator();
        loc1.workbook = wb1;
        loc2.workbook = wb2;

        ExcelComparator excelComparator = new ExcelComparator();
        excelComparator.compareNumberOfSheets(loc1, loc2);
        excelComparator.compareSheetNames(loc1, loc2);
        excelComparator.compareSheetData(loc1, loc2);

        return excelComparator.listOfDifferences;
    }


    private void compareDataInAllSheets(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loc1.workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i ++) {
            if (loc2.workbook.getNumberOfSheets() <= i) {
                return;
            }

            loc1.sheet = loc1.workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            loc2.sheet = loc2.workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            compareDataInSheet(loc1, loc2);
        }
    }

    private void compareDataInSheet(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        for (int j = 0; j <= loc1.sheet.getLastRowNum(); j ++) {
            if (loc2.sheet.getLastRowNum() <= j) {
                return;
            }

            loc1.row = loc1.sheet.getRow(j);
            loc2.row = loc2.sheet.getRow(j);

            if ((loc1.row == null) || (loc2.row == null)) {
                continue;
            }

            compareDataInRow(loc1, loc2);
        }
    }

    private void compareDataInRow(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        for (int k = 0; k <= loc1.row.getLastCellNum(); k ++) {
            if (loc2.row.getLastCellNum() <= k) {
                return;
            }

            loc1.cell = loc1.row.getCell(k);
            loc2.cell = loc2.row.getCell(k);

            if ((loc1.cell == null) || (loc2.cell == null)) {
                continue;
            }

            compareDataInCell(loc1, loc2);
        }
    }

    private void compareDataInCell(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (isCellTypeMatches(loc1, loc2)) {
            final CellType loc1cellType = loc1.cell.getCellType();
            switch (loc1cellType) {
                case BLANK:
                case STRING:
                case ERROR:
                    isCellContentMatches(loc1, loc2);
                    break;
                case BOOLEAN:
                    isCellContentMatchesForBoolean(loc1, loc2);
                    break;
                case FORMULA:
                    isCellContentMatchesForFormula(loc1, loc2);
                    break;
                case NUMERIC:
                    if (DateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(loc1.cell)) {
                        isCellContentMatchesForDate(loc1, loc2);
                    } else {
                        isCellContentMatchesForNumeric(loc1, loc2);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected cell type: " + loc1cellType);
            }
        }

        isCellFillPatternMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellAlignmentMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellHiddenMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellLockedMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellFontFamilyMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellFontSizeMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellFontBoldMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellUnderLineMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellFontItalicsMatches(loc1, loc2);
        isCellBorderMatches(loc1, loc2, 't');
        isCellBorderMatches(loc1, loc2, 'l');
        isCellBorderMatches(loc1, loc2, 'b');
        isCellBorderMatches(loc1, loc2, 'r');
        isCellFillBackGroundMatches(loc1, loc2);
    }


    private void compareNumberOfColumnsInSheets(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loc1.workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i ++) {
            if (loc2.workbook.getNumberOfSheets() <= i) {
                return;
            }

            loc1.sheet = loc1.workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            loc2.sheet = loc2.workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            Iterator<Row> ri1 = loc1.sheet.rowIterator();
            Iterator<Row> ri2 = loc2.sheet.rowIterator();

            int num1 = (ri1.hasNext()) ? ri1.next().getPhysicalNumberOfCells() : 0;
            int num2 = (ri2.hasNext()) ? ri2.next().getPhysicalNumberOfCells() : 0;

            if (num1 != num2) {
                String str = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%s\nworkbook1 -> %s [%d] != workbook2 -> %s [%d]", "Number Of Columns does not Match ::", loc1.sheet.getSheetName(), num1, loc2.sheet.getSheetName(), num2);
                listOfDifferences.add(str);
            }
        }
    }


    private void compareNumberOfRowsInSheets(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loc1.workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i ++) {
            if (loc2.workbook.getNumberOfSheets() <= i) {
                return;
            }

            loc1.sheet = loc1.workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            loc2.sheet = loc2.workbook.getSheetAt(i);

            int num1 = loc1.sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
            int num2 = loc2.sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();

            if (num1 != num2) {
                String str = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%s\nworkbook1 -> %s [%d] != workbook2 -> %s [%d]", "Number Of Rows does not Match ::", loc1.sheet.getSheetName(), num1, loc2.sheet.getSheetName(), num2);
                listOfDifferences.add(str);
            }
        }

    }


    private void compareNumberOfSheets(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        int num1 = loc1.workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        int num2 = loc2.workbook.getNumberOfSheets();
        if (num1 != num2) {
            String str = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%s\nworkbook1 [%d] != workbook2 [%d]", "Number of Sheets do not match ::", num1, num2);

            listOfDifferences.add(str);

        }
    }


    private void compareSheetData(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        compareNumberOfRowsInSheets(loc1, loc2);
        compareNumberOfColumnsInSheets(loc1, loc2);
        compareDataInAllSheets(loc1, loc2);

    }


    private void compareSheetNames(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        for (int i = 0; i < loc1.workbook.getNumberOfSheets(); i ++) {
            String name1 = loc1.workbook.getSheetName(i);
            String name2 = (loc2.workbook.getNumberOfSheets() > i) ? loc2.workbook.getSheetName(i) : "";

            if (!name1.equals(name2)) {
                String str = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%s\nworkbook1 -> %s [%d] != workbook2 -> %s [%d]", "Name of the sheets do not match ::", name1, i + 1, name2, i + 1);
                listOfDifferences.add(str);
            }
        }
    }


    private void addMessage(Locator loc1, Locator loc2, String messageStart, String value1, String value2) {
        String str = String.format(Locale.ROOT, "%s\nworkbook1 -> %s -> %s [%s] != workbook2 -> %s -> %s [%s]", messageStart, loc1.sheet.getSheetName(), new CellReference(loc1.cell).formatAsString(), value1, loc2.sheet.getSheetName(), new CellReference(loc2.cell).formatAsString(), value2);
        listOfDifferences.add(str);
    }

    /**
     * Checks if cell alignment matches.
     */
    private void isCellAlignmentMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        HorizontalAlignment align1 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getAlignment();
        HorizontalAlignment align2 = loc2.cell.getCellStyle().getAlignment();
        if (align1 != align2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Alignment does not Match ::", align1.name(), align2.name());
        }
    }


    private void isCellBorderMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2, char borderSide) {
        if (!(loc1.cell instanceof XSSFCell) || loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        XSSFCellStyle style1 = ((XSSFCell)loc1.cell).getCellStyle();
        XSSFCellStyle style2 = ((XSSFCell)loc2.cell).getCellStyle();
        boolean b1,
        b2;
        String borderName;
        switch (borderSide) {
            case 't':
            default:
                b1 = style1.getBorderTop() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                b2 = style2.getBorderTop() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                borderName = "TOP";
                break;
            case 'b':
                b1 = style1.getBorderBottom() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                b2 = style2.getBorderBottom() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                borderName = "BOTTOM";
                break;
            case 'l':
                b1 = style1.getBorderLeft() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                b2 = style2.getBorderLeft() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                borderName = "LEFT";
                break;
            case 'r':
                b1 = style1.getBorderRight() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                b2 = style2.getBorderRight() == BorderStyle.THIN;
                borderName = "RIGHT";
                break;
        }
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Border Attributes does not Match ::", (b1 ? "" : "NOT ") + borderName + " BORDER", (b2 ? "" : "NOT ") + borderName + " BORDER");
        }
    }


    private void isCellContentMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        String str1 = loc1.cell.toString();
        String str2 = loc2.cell.toString();
        if (!str1.equals(str2)) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_DATA_DOES_NOT_MATCH, str1, str2);
        }
    }


    private void isCellContentMatchesForBoolean(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        boolean b1 = loc1.cell.getBooleanCellValue();
        boolean b2 = loc2.cell.getBooleanCellValue();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_DATA_DOES_NOT_MATCH, Boolean.toString(b1), Boolean.toString(b2));
        }
    }


    private void isCellContentMatchesForDate(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        Date date1 = loc1.cell.getDateCellValue();
        Date date2 = loc2.cell.getDateCellValue();
        if (!date1.equals(date2)) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_DATA_DOES_NOT_MATCH, date1.toString(), date2.toString());
        }
    }


    private void isCellContentMatchesForFormula(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) { // TODO: actually evaluate the formula / NPE checks
        String form1 = loc1.cell.getCellFormula();
        String form2 = loc2.cell.getCellFormula();
        if (!form1.equals(form2)) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_DATA_DOES_NOT_MATCH, form1, form2);
        }
    }


    private void isCellContentMatchesForNumeric(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) { // TODO: Check for NaN
        double num1 = loc1.cell.getNumericCellValue();
        double num2 = loc2.cell.getNumericCellValue();
        if (num1 != num2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_DATA_DOES_NOT_MATCH, Double.toString(num1), Double.toString(num2));
        }
    }

    private String getCellFillBackground(Locator loc) {
        Color col = loc.cell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColorColor();
        return(col instanceof XSSFColor) ? ((XSSFColor)col).getARGBHex() : "NO COLOR";
    }


    private void isCellFillBackGroundMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        String col1 = getCellFillBackground(loc1);
        String col2 = getCellFillBackground(loc2);
        if (!col1.equals(col2)) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Fill Color does not Match ::", col1, col2);
        }
    }

    private void isCellFillPatternMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        FillPatternType fill1 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getFillPattern();
        FillPatternType fill2 = loc2.cell.getCellStyle().getFillPattern();
        if (fill1 != fill2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Fill pattern does not Match ::", fill1.name(), fill2.name());
        }
    }


    private void isCellFontBoldMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (!(loc1.cell instanceof XSSFCell) || loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (hasInvalidFontIndex(loc1, loc2)) {
            return;
        }

        boolean b1 = ((XSSFCell)loc1.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getBold();
        boolean b2 = ((XSSFCell)loc2.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getBold();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_FONT_ATTRIBUTES_DOES_NOT_MATCH, (b1 ? "" : "NOT ") + "BOLD", (b2 ? "" : "NOT ") + "BOLD");
        }
    }


    private void isCellFontFamilyMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (!(loc1.cell instanceof XSSFCell) || loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (hasInvalidFontIndex(loc1, loc2)) {
            return;
        }

        String family1 = ((XSSFCell)loc1.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontName();
        String family2 = ((XSSFCell)loc2.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontName();
        if (!family1.equals(family2)) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Font Family does not Match ::", family1, family2);
        }
    }

    private boolean hasInvalidFontIndex(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        int fontIdx1 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndexAsInt();
        int fontCount1 = ((XSSFWorkbook)loc1.workbook).getStylesSource().getFonts().size();
        int fontIdx2 = loc2.cell.getCellStyle().getFontIndexAsInt();
        int fontCount2 = ((XSSFWorkbook)loc2.workbook).getStylesSource().getFonts().size();

        if (fontIdx1 >= fontCount1 || fontIdx2 >= fontCount2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Corrupted file, cell style references a font which is not defined", Integer.toString(fontIdx1), Integer.toString(fontIdx2));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }


    private void isCellFontItalicsMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (!(loc1.cell instanceof XSSFCell) || loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (hasInvalidFontIndex(loc1, loc2)) {
            return;
        }

        boolean b1 = ((XSSFCell)loc1.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getItalic();
        boolean b2 = ((XSSFCell)loc2.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getItalic();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_FONT_ATTRIBUTES_DOES_NOT_MATCH, (b1 ? "" : "NOT ") + "ITALICS", (b2 ? "" : "NOT ") + "ITALICS");
        }
    }


    private void isCellFontSizeMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (!(loc1.cell instanceof XSSFCell) || loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (hasInvalidFontIndex(loc1, loc2)) {
            return;
        }

        short size1 = ((XSSFCell)loc1.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontHeightInPoints();
        short size2 = ((XSSFCell)loc2.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getFontHeightInPoints();
        if (size1 != size2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Font Size does not Match ::", Short.toString(size1), Short.toString(size2));
        }
    }


    private void isCellHiddenMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        boolean b1 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getHidden();
        boolean b2 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getHidden();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Visibility does not Match ::", (b1 ? "" : "NOT ") + "HIDDEN", (b2 ? "" : "NOT ") + "HIDDEN");
        }
    }


    private void isCellLockedMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        if (loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        boolean b1 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getLocked();
        boolean b2 = loc1.cell.getCellStyle().getLocked();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Protection does not Match ::", (b1 ? "" : "NOT ") + "LOCKED", (b2 ? "" : "NOT ") + "LOCKED");
        }
    }


    private boolean isCellTypeMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) {
        CellType type1 = loc1.cell.getCellType();
        CellType type2 = loc2.cell.getCellType();
        if (type1 == type2) {
            return true;
        }

        addMessage(loc1, loc2, "Cell Data-Type does not Match in :: ", type1.name(), type2.name());
        return false;
    }


    private void isCellUnderLineMatches(Locator loc1, Locator loc2) { // TODO: distinguish underline type

        if (!(loc1.cell instanceof XSSFCell) || loc1.cell.getCellStyle() == null || loc2.cell.getCellStyle() == null) {
            return;
        }

        if (hasInvalidFontIndex(loc1, loc2)) {
            return;
        }

        byte b1 = ((XSSFCell)loc1.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getUnderline();
        byte b2 = ((XSSFCell)loc2.cell).getCellStyle().getFont().getUnderline();
        if (b1 != b2) {
            addMessage(loc1, loc2, CELL_FONT_ATTRIBUTES_DOES_NOT_MATCH, (b1 == 1 ? "" : "NOT ") + "UNDERLINE", (b2 == 1 ? "" : "NOT ") + "UNDERLINE");
        }
    }
}
```

Expected output

input to be asked when executed
Provide the PreUpgrade files Folder Path:   E:\PreUpgrade\
Provide the PostUpgrade files Folder Path:  E:\PostUpgrade\

output
Comparison Results must be placed in this folder, with Compared_${fileName}
E:\Comparison\

NOTE: File Names in both the folders should be like Pre-${fileName} & Post-${fileName} while input is provided

P.S: This is my first time posting here pls ignore mistakes if any

Comment: You don't need to put the path to your excel files in the code, but pass it as an argument to the program when you execute it. [See here for help](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fmenus%2Frun%2Fref-open_run_dialog.htm).

Comment: could you please elaborate on how to do that as my main stream is not java and i am a fresher. and also when i am executing it eclipse is showing this:

Answer (score 0):

try to build your program (generate the .jar file) and run this command in the command prompt:

```
java -jar pathtoyourjarfile.jar file1 file2
```

Comment: java -cp <classpath> org.apache.poi.ss.examples.ExcelComparator <workbook1.xls/x> <workbook2.xls/x

Comment: that was what the console was showing me when i try to build.

Comment: start compiling your java class (ExcelComparator .java) with the folowing command: `javac pathOfYourJavaFile.java` , this command will generate a .class file, you will then run this command: `java yourClassFile file1 file2` ...you must provide the path of the class file without the extension .class...Hope this helps

Comment: i tried that but i am not able to import all the libraries. when i try using javac in command prompt its showing me 78 errors as the libraries are external. i need a way to import the library files and then can try your method

Comment: if you have Eclipse installed or Netbeans, create a java application project with your class as the Main class and add all the lib needed, then all you need to do is right click the project an select _build_ you'll have a jar file generated in your project folder (ex: "dist" folder if you use netbeans) then you can run the jar file with the previous command in my answer

Comment: Thank you so much that helped. But now i need help in modifying the code in a way that the result gets generated in an excel sheet instead of showing in command prompt and i need to provide the input files using directory of their location instead of pasting every file at the location of my jar file.

Comment: Glad I helped!I will appreciate if you upvote my answer :)

Comment: sure but also please help me out in modifying the code as asked in the above comment

Comment: Ok i will do that